# Connect to ADLS with Spark API in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-data-lake, azure-databricks

I am trying to establish a connection to an ADLS using a Spark API. I am really new to this. I read the documentation where it says that you can establish the connection with the following code:

```
spark.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
spark.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.client.id", "<application-id>")
spark.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.credential", dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "<scope-name>", key = "<key-name-for-service-credential>"))
spark.conf.set("fs.adl.oauth2.refresh.url", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token")
```

I can see in the Azure Portal / Azure Storage Explorer that I have Read/Write/Execute permission on the ADLS folder that I need, but I don't know where to find `application-id`, `scope-name`, and `key-name-for-service-credential`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of accessing Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1:

1. Mount an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 filesystem to DBFS using a
   service principal and OAuth 2.0.
2. Use a service principal directly.

**Prerequisites:**

You need to Create and grant permissions to service principal.

[Create an Azure AD application and service principal that can access resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal).

Note the following properties:

**application-id:** An ID that uniquely identifies the client application.

**directory-id:** An ID that uniquely identifies the Azure AD instance.

**service-credential:** A string that the application uses to prove its identity.

Register the service principal, granting the correct [role assignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-secure-data), such as Contributor, on the Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 account.

**Method1:** Mount Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 resource or folder

[image]

**Method2:** Access directly with Spark APIs using a service principal and OAuth 2.0

[image]

Method3: Access directly with Spark APIs using a service principal and OAuth 2.0 with dbutils.secrets.get(scope = "", key = "") retrieves your storage account access key that has been stored as a secret in a secret scope.

[image]

**Reference:** [Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake.html#).